# How to find the last two digits of $237^{222222212202}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

## Problem

Finding the last two digits of a base with a large exponent:
$237^{222222212202}$.

## Method

1. If the number ends on 1:

   - the the second last digit is the second last base digit times the last exponent digit
   - the last digit is 1
2. If the number ends on odd:

   - rewrite it until it is a number that ends on one and the first rule can be used $((n^4)^{e/4})$
3. If the number ends on an even number:

   - $..76^{n} = ..76$
   - $..24^{n} = $ ..76 for even $n$ and 24 for uneven $n$
   - $..2^{10} = ..24$

## Solution

$$(7^4)^{55555553050}\cdot 7^2 = (2401)^{..0} \cdot 7^2 = ..01 \cdot 7^2 = 49$$

## Question

- Is this method correct / could it be improved?
- Is there an easier method?
- Can someone please take my example and demonstrate it with Euler and explain it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I got  $69$, using $37$, not $7$

Comment: are you familiar with congruence?

Comment: @Arnaldo yeah, that is modulo calculation, right?

Comment: Right, so you're essentially asking for $237^{222222212202}\mod 100$

Comment: Are you familiar with Eulers formula?  That $\phi(100) = 40$ and so $237^{40}\equiv 1\pmod {100}$?  The last two digits will cycle in a pattern the pattern will repeat every $40$ times.  But to know that, you have to know Euler's formula.  If you don't just try powering $237$ until you get the pattern.

Comment: @fleablood I've seen Euler's formula a lot. But I don't get it. What is that phi and why do we use 100?

Comment: @HeinrichJensen:  Euler’s theorem is $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod n$ if $\gcd(a,n)=1$

Comment: I don't mean Eulers equation, $e^{\pi i}=-1$.  I mean Eulers formula that if $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime and $\phi(n)$ is the number of positive integers less than $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$, then $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$.  So as there are $40$ numbers between $1$ and $100$ that are relatively prime to $100$ then $237^{40}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$ and the last to digits of $237^{40}$ are $01$. And so the last two digits of $237^{222222212200}$ are $01$ (because $40|222222212200$) and the last to digits of $237^{222222212202}$ is the last two digits of $37^2$.

Comment: The trick is to realize the last digit (or the last two digits) cycle.  It's easy by trial and error to see that the last digit of $7^4$ is $1$ so the last digit of $7^{4m}$ is always $1$ So the last digit of $237^{4M + 2}$ the last digit of $7^2$ is $9$... But for the last *two* digits the cycle isn't $4$ long it is $20$ long. But I can't think of any easy way to figure that out be trial and error.

Comment: Oops.  You are right.  My result is Euler's *THEOREM*.  Euler's formula is usually the equation $e^{\pi i} = -1$ (but sometimes it is that for a polyhedron The number of Faces + the number of edges - the number of Vertices = 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints to compute $237^{222222212202}\mod 100$:**

If $a\equiv b \mod 100$ then $a^n\equiv b^n\bmod 100$.

$a^{20}\equiv1\mod 100$ if $a$ is relatively prime to $100$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $a^{40}$, since $\varphi(100)=40$?

Comment: @LukeCollins:  The Carmichael function of $100$ is $20$

Comment: @JW Ah, I see, thanks. So $\lambda(100) \neq \varphi(100)$ since $(\mathbb Z/100\mathbb Z)^\times$ is not cyclic.

Comment: The only real question is what level do we assume the OP is at?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple way to go about this, you basically want to evaluate $237^{222222212202}\bmod 100$. Now in any group $G$ with $n$ elements, we have $g^n = 1$ for all $g$. Thus if we look at your number as a member of the group $(\mathbb Z/100\mathbb Z)^\times$, we get that
$$237^{222222212202}=(237^{100})^{2222222122}\cdot 237^2 = 1^{2222222122}\cdot 237^2 = 237^2,$$
thus you just need to look at the last two digits of $237^2$, which are $69$.