# Calculate the n-th number of a power with huge exponent

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, power-series, big-numbers

There are several questions asked (e.g. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3607092/474480), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3472570/474480) or [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/634238/474480)) on the last digit of numbers like $7^{355}$ or $237^{222222212202237}$.

My question is, if there is any efficient method to calculate the n-th digit of these numbers. To get the n-th digit, one could evaluate $7^{355} \mod 10^{n}$, but this seems not appropriate for large numbers $n$.

---

Example:

Calculate the second last digit (in base 10) of $237^{222222212202237}$. We calculate $237^{222222212202237} \mod 10^{2}$ and receive 69, so the answer is "6". But how would one get e.g. the thirty-first last digit?

Comment: You seem to mean the $n^{th}$ last digit, for which modular arithmetic seems to be the answer (values are periodic). If you were to mean the $n^{th}$ most significant digit, the standard answer would be sufficiently accurate logarithms.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i addressed it by providing an example.

Comment: A little brute force finds that $237^{20} \equiv 1\bmod 100$, and $2222222\dots 237 \equiv 17 \bmod 20$. Thus $237^{2222222\dots 237} \equiv 237^{17} \bmod 100$, and finally $237^{2222222\dots 237} \equiv 17 \bmod 100$, not $69$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "square and reduce" method of modular exponentiation is pretty efficient.  With your large numbers, it's still going to be tedious and probably impossible to do by hand.  Here's a smaller example than yours, just to illustrate.

Suppose I want the 3rd last digit of $47^{57}$.  So I need to reduce it mod $1000.$   Write the exponent in binary:  $57 = 111001$. This shows you that $47^{57} = 47^{32}47^{16}47^{8}47^1.$  Repeatedly square $47$ and reduce mod $1000$:

$$47^1 \equiv 47 \pmod{1000}$$
$$47^2 \equiv 209 \pmod{1000}$$
$$47^4 \equiv 681 \pmod{1000}$$
$$47^8 \equiv 761 \pmod{1000}$$
$$47^{16} \equiv 121 \pmod{1000}$$
$$47^{32} \equiv 641 \pmod{1000}$$

Then $$47^{57} \equiv 47^{32}47^{16}47^{8}47^1 \equiv 641\cdot 121 \cdot 761 \cdot 47 \equiv 287 \pmod{1000}.$$

So the answer is $2$.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question (probably because this was posted before the question was edited to include an example).

Comment: @Snaw The question was "is there an efficient method." I gave a method that is $O(\ln n)$.  Pretty efficient.  So who knows what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm referring to "But how would one get e.g. the thirty-first last digit?". I'm not saying there's a better answer-- only that there is no way to do what OP is asking for by hand (as far as I know).

Comment: @Snaw  He didn't say "by hand." He said "efficient."